# How can I get my hoverzoom effect to work only on one object and not all objects?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to fix my code to allow for Mui `<cards>` to create a hover effect when a user's mouse is over the object. I have it working to an extent, however, the effect is applied to all objects, not one.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-cookies-o23ps

I have replicated a sandbox for this issue.

Here is the code that is used for the hovering effect:

```css
    root: {
        maxWidth: 310,
        transition: "transform 0.15s ease-in-out",
        "&:hover": { transform: "scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1)" },
      }
```

```js
                <Card
                  className={classes.root}
                  classes={{ root: state.raised ? classes.cardHovered : "" }}
                  onMouseOver={() => setState({ raised: true, shadow: 3 })}
                  onMouseOut={() => setState({ raised: false, shadow: 1 })}
                  raised={state.raised}
                  zdepth={state.shadow}
                >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing state.raised and state.shadow on mouseOver and mouseOut to apply a different style but since it's those are state variable is actually changing every card to the same property raised and zdepth.

I would suggest you do try to achieved the desired raised and shadow state with the same css class you are using.

onMouseOut means the mouse it's not on it, so adding the shadow: 1 effect you are trying to achieve to the root css class will do the trick. And then add the raised and shadow: 3 effect to the &:hover.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, do you mean creating a conditional that switches to the desired CSS?

Comment: Since what you want is to add the raised effect to the card when the mouse is hovering, you can just add `box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);` to the hover pseudo.

Comment: The issue itself that you are having is that every single Card is changing the state `raised` and `shadow`. Since it's a unique value, every other card is also using the same state that is changed by hovering any card.

The solution is to either have an individual state for every card (which I do not recommend for obvious reason) or using css to achieve the desired effect in each element individually. That can be done by just changing the root class.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wood-riqfe?file=/src/App.js) where I fixed it.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for the help and fiddle!